# How can I get an item position

Tags: android

I have a listview filled of words
Hello,
How are you,
Good morning,
How do you do,
I use search in this listview by voice recorder in textedit but this method only filter my words in fact I just need to get the position of the result of item
Example:
When I say "Good morning"
I don't want to filter only the item has good morning but I want to get the number of it position
Like here we have the sentence "good morning" in the item number 2 so I need to get 2 not filtering
Maybe someone here has the solution please

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.textItem, wordslist);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);


            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you have tried ?
Show us some code !

Comment: Please check it now I edited

Answer (score 1):

Simple pass the filtered word like below, if your wordslist is a type of list you can get index of item by simply

```
int index = wordslist.indexOf("good morning");
```